# Jasmine spy on imported module (typescript)

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I am trying to test a simple utility class with static methods with jasmine and typescript. The problem is the helper class imports a 3rd party library to achieve a goal. I need to test that this 3rd party library is called in every situation.

```
import Helpers from '../../src/utils/Helpers';
import {parseString} from 'xml2js';



describe('Helper class', function() {
  let mockParseString: any;

  describe('xmlToJson', function() {
    beforeEach(function(done) {
      mockParseString = jasmine.createSpy('parseString', parseString);
      // spyOn(xml2js, 'parseString').and.callFake(function(xml: string, callback: (error: any, data: object) => void) {
      //
      // });

      setTimeout(() => {
        done();
      }, 1);
    })


    it('calls library to parse string', async function(done) {
      await Helpers.xmlToJson('<div></div>');

      expect(mockParseString).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    })
  })
});
```

Then in helper class I'm just wrapping a callback function in a promise:

```
import {convertableToString, OptionsV2, parseString} from 'xml2js';
export default class Helpers {
  public static xmlToJson(xml: convertableToString, options?: OptionsV2): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(options) {
        parseString(xml, (err, results) => {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          resolve(results);
        });
      } else {
        parseString(xml, options, (err, results) => {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          resolve(results);
        });
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The error I get is that the spy is not called. I have dug around for awhile but I have not found a way to get the spy to work. Maybe it is simply not possible.

**EDIT**

How I am calling the test:

```
 ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine spec/utils/Helpers-spec.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I could not get this to work to work by referencing the library implicitly. I opted to use a dependency injection solution instead and have my class be a service. This is probably cleaner in the end anyways. (I still need to cleanup types as this is pretty bleh)

```
import {convertableToString, OptionsV2, parseString} from 'xml2js';

export default class Helpers {
  parseString: any;

  constructor(parseString: any) {
    this.parseString = parseString;
  }
  public xmlToJson(xml: convertableToString, options?: OptionsV2): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if(options) {
        this.parseString(xml, (err: any, results: string) => {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          resolve(results);
        });
      } else {
        this.parseString(xml, options, (err: any, results: string) => {
          if(err) {
            reject(err);
          }

          resolve(results);
        });
      }
    })
  }
}
```

And then barebones test with:

```
import Helpers from '../../src/utils/helpers';
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';

describe('Helper class', function() {

  let mockParseString:any;

  describe('xmlToJson', function() {

    beforeAll(() => {
      mockParseString = spyOn(xml2js, 'parseString').and.callThrough();
    });

    it('calls library to parse string', async (done) => {
      let helper = new Helpers(mockParseString);

      await helper.xmlToJson('<div></div>');
      expect(mockParseString).toHaveBeenCalled();
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

Thanks to @brian-lives-outdoors for help though!

Comment: buphmin - but when i use import statement, i got cannot use import statement outside a module angularjs.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working test for your code:

```
import Helpers from '../../src/utils/Helpers';
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';

describe('Helper class', function() {

  let mockParseString;

  describe('xmlToJson', function() {

    beforeAll(() => {
      mockParseString = spyOn(xml2js, 'parseString').and.callThrough();
    });

    it('calls library to parse string', (done) => {
      (async () => {
        await Helpers.xmlToJson('<div></div>');
        expect(mockParseString).toHaveBeenCalled();
      })().then(() => done());
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, weekend and all. I tried that but no luck. It could be that the way I am running is causing a problem, I am using ts-node to run the test. I additionally tried to set the logic so it always calls parseString (as a control) still no luck.

Comment: @buphmin I updated my answer to contain a working test, let me know if it works for you

Comment: @buphmin updated to inline the async function and call `done()` on completion (forgot this was Jasmine)

Comment: Still no go, spy not called. I will try a few more things, but I suspect it will probably be better to inject the library into the constructor of the class anyways.

Comment: @buphmin weird.  try one more thing for me, add `await Promise.resolve();` before the `expect` to let the event loop cycle one more time before asserting.  If that doesn't work then I don't know, the code and test above work fine in my environment

Comment: still no, I am will update the question too, but I am using "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node ./node_modules/.bin/jasmine spec/utils/Helpers-spec.ts" to run the test. I did; however get it to function by injecting parseString into the class and changing from a static function. Similar to a symfony service if you're familiar with that.

Comment: huh, glad you got it to work a different way.  I set up ts-node in a new project and called the test the same way and it worked fine, must be something different in the config/environment